# nginx proxy path with prefix for multiple apps

Tags: nginx

I've got a problem in configuration nginx proxy_pass. There's a situation like this:

- Server 1 - xx.xx.xx.xx - proxy server
- Server 2 with application A - yy.yy.yy.yy
- Server 3 with application B - zz.zz.zz.zz

Configuration listed below:

```
server {
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied


    location /app_a {
        rewrite /app_a/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass http://yy.yy.yy.yy/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Upstream $remote_addr;


}

    location /app_b {
        rewrite /app_b/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        access_log off;
        proxy_pass http://zz.zz.zz.zz;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header Client-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Upstream $remote_addr;
    }

}
```

Then when I go with my browser xx.xx.xx.xx/app_a or xx.xx.xx.xx/app_b there is no static files loaded (404) and all links are without application prefix (xx.xx.xx.xx/login)

How I can configure nginx so the links will be displayed like:

- xx.xx.xx.xx/app_a/login
- xx.xx.xx.xx/app_b/login

Comment: You should phrase a question out of your post.

Comment: Actually I believe that this is an app issue, the app `app_a` and `app_b` should be set that their root path is `http://example.com/app_a` and `http://example.com/app_b`, nginx isn't responsible to rewrite those URL's in the responses